# Characters Escaping issue

Tags: c#, wpf, string, escaping, app-config

I am working on WPF application and now I have part of my code that has to add content to my app.config file.

Simply said I have to add a Key-Value pair as a child of a particular element but when I try to add it the escaping symbols are changing and I dont know why.

I am giving you an example:

I want to add :

```
<add key="MyKey" value="&lt;add name=&quot;{0}&quot; /&gt;_#ss_dsa">
```

after the appSettings tag.When I am doing it manualy it works but when I try to add it by code-behind I am doing this:

```
 var appPath=Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
 var appConfigFile = Path.Combine( appPath, "MyApp.exe" ); 
 var config= ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(appConfigFile);
```

and then:

```
config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("Key","Value");
```

is supposed to add `<add key="Key" value="Value">`

to the app.config AND IT DOES, but when I pass this:

```
"&lt;add name=&quot;{0}&quot; /&gt;_#ss_dsa"
```

for the value it transforms it into :

```
"&amp;lt;add name=&amp;quot;{0}&amp;quot; /&amp;gt;_#ss_dsa"
```

in the app.config file.I don't really know why is this happening and how can I fix it.
It would be great if someone could give an advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *value* expected is unescaped. So *add it* unescaped: try adding:

```
blah.Add("MyKey", @"<add name=""{0}"" />_#ss_dsa");
```

where the `""` in the middle are C# escaping - the actual string here is

```
<add name="{0}" />_#ss_dsa
```